# How does server path work on uploading and downloading files?

Tags: asp.net

How does the server path work?

Im uploading the files on the physical application on asp webforms, so the files are stored on my my application with the following code

string nombrearchivo = archivo.FileName;

```
                    string carpeta = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "subirarchivos");
                    carpeta = Path.Combine(carpeta, aux);

                    carpeta = Path.Combine(carpeta, "PROPUESTA");
                    if (Directory.Exists(carpeta))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta);
                        archivo.SaveAs(carpeta);

                    }
```

Now i have uploaded the files into a windows server with this route:

http::\servername\AppName\FormOrden.aspx

```
       string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles");
       archivo.SaveAs(pathToFiles);
```

As i know you can use that code to upload files into the server, but where does it stored on physical server and how does it work on uploading and downloading, since i cant find the files on server?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` is relative to the IIS virtual directory.

Comment: @DanielA.White it's a asp.net Webform application running on windows server 2012

Comment: @alex: You can go to your web app directory, under parent directory you'll have "UploadedFiles" directory where uploaded files will be stored

Comment: @DipenShah i can't find the folder "UploadedFiles" on server :/

Comment: @alex, If your code work, I bet you, it is there.

Comment: @DipenShah When i use the code "Physical path" it's stored on parent folder and its working, however while using server path i cant find the files. I dont know the difference between these two and if the application will work when it goes online working on physical path.

Comment: @alex When you use `Server.MapPath` and run it in Visual Studio, it refers to your `project folder\UploadedFiles`. 
But when you run it on IIS, it means `Virtual Directory(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite)\UploadedFiles`

Comment: @DipenShah thanks alot, now i understood it's process and it's storing files and downloading them now :)